# Does type aliases create new name?

Tags: typescript

I am reading TypeScript Documentation.

In [Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) section, it says:

> Type aliases create a new name for a type.

In [Interfaces vs. Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases) section, it says:

> Type aliases don’t create a new name — for instance, error messages won’t use the alias name.

Does type aliases create new name?

Comment: I think it should be "Type aliases don’t create a new type — for instance, error messages won’t use the alias name since they can only use type's name", but it looks a bit messy due to the fact that `type` keyword does not create a type.